# Type hinting a method accepting a type (possibly ABC) and returning instances of that type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have classes like this:

```py
class Transaction(ABC):
    self.uuid: str

class CashTransaction(Transaction):
    ...

class SecurityTransaction(Transaction):
    ...
```

Instances of the classes above are stored in a class called RecordKeeper, which has a method for getting a list of the instances. The method accepts either of the three classes defined above and checks that all the instances are of this specified type.

The following implementation works with mypy, but not when type_ is Transaction (the ABC):

```py
class RecordKeeper:
    self._transactions: list[Transaction]

    TransactionType = TypeVar("TransactionType", Transaction, CashTransaction, SecurityTransaction)

    def get_transactions(
        self,
        uuids: Collection[str],
        type_: type[TransactionType],
    ) -> list[TransactionType]:
        """Returns a list of Transactions matching uuuids, ensuring they are all of type 'type_'."""

    # correctly inferred list[CashTransaction]
    cash_transactions = self.get_transactions(uuids, CashTransaction)

    # correctly inferred list[SecurityTransaction]
    security_transactions = self.get_transactions(uuids, SecurityTransaction)

    # VS Code type checker correctly infers any_transactions: list[Transaction], but mypy fails:
    # Only concrete class can be given where "Type[Transaction]" is expected [type-abstract]
    any_transactions = self.get_transactions(uuids, Transaction)
```

I tried using overloads like this:

```py
    @overload
    def get_transactions(
        self, uuids: Collection[str], type_: type[CashTransaction]) -> list[CashTransaction]:
        ...

    @overload
    def get_transactions(
        self, uuids: Collection[str], type_: type[SecurityTransaction]) -> list[SecurityTransaction]:
        ...

    @overload
    def get_transactions(
        self, uuids: Collection[str], type_: type[Transaction]) -> list[Transaction]:
        ...

    def get_transactions(
        self, uuids: Collection[str], type_: type[TransactionType]) -> list[TransactionType]:
        # actual implementation here
```

but that leads to errors like this: `Overloaded function signatures 1 and 3 overlap with incompatible return types  [misc]`

Is there any solution that would work when the ABC is supplied as the type_?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Currently your code has a lot of undefined symbols. I tried to find out what you mean, but the error [does not reproduce in playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=7488e49431c627076b2bade741974d73), so please provide `mypy` and python versions as well.

Comment: @SUTerliakov hello, so I tried to produce the MRE and turns out the error only appears when there is an abstract method defined in the ABC. I [edited](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=7488e49431c627076b2bade741974d73) your playground script slightly and now the error is visible. BTW my Python is 3.11.2 and mypy is 1.0.0.

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4717

Comment: @SUTerliakov I see, so no solution for this now within mypy. Thanks!